# 2nd product discount for Drupal 7 Ubercart

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I have a client who asked this.

The original product price is $26. But when we order 2nd product and after that is going to be $22 per item.
So if I order 3 products the total would be 26 + 22 + 22 = $70

Is there a module that can do this or any workaround ? I have searched and I could find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you're looking for, set a price and a min quantity to get that price

[Ubercart Volume pricing](https://drupal.org/project/uc_volume_pricing)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a product quantity discount with this module:

https://drupal.org/project/uc_coupon

This module is also another possible solution:

https://drupal.org/project/uc_discounts_alt